# Validation of Database date and JQuery date

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, date

I am new to PHP. I am using mysql. I have to compare two dates and return a result only when both the dates match. One of the dates is from the database and the other is from jquery UI Datepicker which should be stored in the database. The problem here is that the format of both the dates is different and I am unable to validate them. Example: The dates in the database are in the yyyy-mm-dd format and the date selected using the datepicker is in the dd-mm-yyyy format. 
 This selected date must be displayed in the same dd-mm-yyyy format. And after searching a lot I found that the format cannot be changed in the database. The selected date should be checked with a column containing 5 date values. So, how can do this? I haven't stored the selected date in the database yet.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
   });
$('form#dateform').submit(function(){   
var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
if(aselectedDate !=''){
alert('selected  ' +aselectedDate); }
return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: you want to compare dates in JQuery or PHP?

Comment: I want to compare the aselectedDate(I will store this value in a table) and the dates in another table.

Comment: you can assign the datepicker dateFormat to 'yyyy-mm-dd' so that it can be inserted to mysql

Comment: Yes, why don't you change the date format of datepicker?

Answer (score 2):

If i am getting what you want, you can make use of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
function. It converts datetime string passed to it to Unix timestamp which you can use for comparison.

If date from datepicker is `21-10-2015` then the function will return `1445385600`
and if the date stroed in db is `2015-10-21` then also the function will return `1445385600`
so you can comapre the two easiyl.

```
$var1 = strtotime('2015-10-21');

$var2 = strtotime('21-10-2015');
```

Then comparison can be made as `if($var1 == $var2)`

Answer (score 0):

To compare both dates(One from MySQL and Another From jQuery Date Picker), you first need to make both date in same format.

There are two ways you can do that:

**First Method with String Comparison ( If you want Date to be displayed in 'dd-mm-yy' Format )**

Convert MySQL Date to jQuery Date Format:

```
<?php
    $DateFromDatabase = "2015-10-21"; // 'yyyy-mm-dd' from MySQL Database
?>
<script>

// 'd-m-y' in php => result in 'dd-mm-yy' format
var $ConvertedDate = "<?php echo date("d-m-y",strtotime($DateFromDatabase)); ?>";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
    });
    $('#dateform').submit(function(){   
        var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
        if($ConvertedDate == aselectedDate){
            alert("Both Dates Matched...");
        } else {
            alert("Dates Not Matched...");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Second Method with String Comparison ( If Date Format is not an issue )**

Change DatePicker Date Format to MySQL Date Format:

```
<?php
    $DateFromDatabase = "2015-10-21"; // 'yyyy-mm-dd' from MySQL Database
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"   
    });
    $('#dateform').submit(function(){   
        var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
        if($DateFromDatabase == aselectedDate){
            alert("Both Dates Matched...");
        } else {
            alert("Dates Not Matched...");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**First Method with Date Object Comparison with Various Operators**

Here we need Date Object for both MySQL Date String as well as DatePicker String. To do that thing,

1) Create Date Object by Parsing Date String from MySQL Database in JavaScript

```
var $ConvertedDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo $DateFromDatabase; ?>"));
```

2) Get the UTC Date Object from the DatePicker Method `'getUTCDate'`

```
var $aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getUTCDate');
```

Here both Date Object must be UTC Date Object because, php date will return UTC Date and JavaScript date will return Date in Milliseconds.

Then we can compare both dates with `'getTime()'`

Here is the complete solution:

```
<?php
    $DateFromDatabase = "2015-10-21"; // 'yyyy-mm-dd' from MySQL Database
?>
<script>

// Parse php UTCDate into JavaScript UTCDate
var $ConvertedDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo $DateFromDatabase; ?>"));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
    });
    $('#dateform').submit(function(){ 

        var $aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getUTCDate');

        if($aselectedDate.getTime() < $ConvertedDate.getTime()){
            alert("Selected Date is Smaller than Database Date");
        } else  if($aselectedDate.getTime() > $ConvertedDate.getTime()){
            alert("Selected Date is Greater than Database Date");
        } else  if($aselectedDate.getTime() === $ConvertedDate.getTime()){
            alert("Selected Date is Equal To Database Date");
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In the first method, aren't we comparing a string value to a date value here in    if($ConvertedDate == aselectedDate) ?